# How can I hide a field on a Parse object

Tags: parse-platform

I added some custom fields in my User class and I would like to hide some of them to the users like the password and verifiedEmail ones.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to hide them from other users who can possibly see them? Or are you trying to hide them when tryiing to retrieve them?

Answer (score 0):

When querying an object, you can specify which fields should be returned by using the `selectKeys` method.

Here is an example for iOS:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query selectKeys:@[@"playerName", @"score"]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
    // objects in results will only contain the playerName and score fields
}];
```

And one for Android:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("playerName", "score"));;
List<ParseObject> results = query.find();
```

If you're developing on another platform, consult the relevant documentation for the one you use (https://www.parse.com/docs/).